# Password field is not populated

Tags: c#

i have password textbox in that when user click on remeber me i want to populate name and password in respective textboxes only name is getting populated not password
i am storing name and password in cookies

i set textmode as password of textbox
also i have forms authentication
i also tried

```
txtpwd.Attributes.Add(value,txtpwd.text)
```

but no success
any help
appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can set the password value by setting its value attribute:

```
txtpwd.Attributes["value"] = "password";
```

Comment: Thanks for the straight answer w/o preaching the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a by-design security feature.  "Remember me" is a matter for [setting a cookie](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443), not for rendering a password in plain text in the HTML being delivered to the client.  Never "show" a password.

**Edit:** In fact, you shouldn't even *have* the actual password to render.  If you're storing passwords in plain text, please do the world a favor and stop it.  One-way hashing is the only way to go for storing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pre-populate a into a password field... and for good reason!

You should either remember that they chose to "Remember Me" and log them in automatically or leave remembering credentials to the browser!